# Using ruby to modify a PDF

Tags: ruby, pdf

I'm about to start a project. I would like to be able to edit a PDF file (forms) using rails.

What is the best (and most simple) solution for this?

So exactly what I need is something that would allow me to **modify an existing PDF file** (a form) and allow the user to print it. Probably their name and stuff.

Help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Do you mean producing a PDF from scratch, or modifying an existing PDF?

Comment: What a relation of Rails to PDF?

Comment: I meant to modify an existing PDF

Comment: iTextSharp? http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=iTextSharp+%2Brails

Comment: Mind being a bit more specific please?

Answer (score 0):

you can try pdf-stamper. I am working on fill pdf form fields now.here is my solution.

```
@template = PDF::Stamper.new(@form.pdf.current_path)

fields = @template.extract_fields

@form.form_fields.each do |ff|
  if fields.has_key?(ff.pdf_field)
    val = form_data.get_value(ff)
    render_field(@template, ff, val)
  else
    BindFile.logger.warn "Key '#{ff.pdf_field}' Not Found".center(100, "-")
  end
end

def render_field(templet, form_field, val)
   if val.present?
      case form_field.pdf_field_type
      when "CheckBox"
        if val.present?
          templet.checkbox form_field.pdf_field
        end
      when "RadioButton"
        templet.send("radio_button", form_field.pdf_field, "Yes")
      when "", nil
        templet.send "text", form_field.pdf_field, val
      else
        templet.send(form_field.pdf_field_type.to_s.downcase, form_field.pdf_field, val)
      end
    end
end
```

here I enhanced pdf-stamper add a method "extract_fields". and use database record to manage  pdf documents. hope helpful for you.

Answer (score -2):

If you are looking for a ruby library for this then you can think of [prawn](https://github.com/sandal/prawn)